# Failover Configuration in Apache HTTPD

Tags: apache, tomcat7, failover

I have an Apache HTTPD Server and two Tomcat Instances (1&2). I want to route all the requests to Tomcat Instance 1, and if and only if Tomcat Instance 1 is down - route all the requests to Tomcat Instance 2. Is this possible? I tried using mod_jk, but this is only doing load balancing. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with below properties.

```
# Define preferred failover node for worker1
  worker.worker1.redirect=worker2

# Disable worker2 for all requests except failover
  worker.worker2.activation=disabled
```